# Are there any ways to speed up pexpect or use a builtin python function?

Tags: python, pexpect

I have an interactive console program that I need to extract data from.  I enter an ID number and it prints out about 10 lines of text that I read and then I repeat.  I previously wrote a C program and used QProcess.  I am porting the code over to python.  I cannot use popen.communicate because it is interactive (I need to send more than one input).

Code is something like this:

```
import pexpect
p=pexpect.spawn(exe_path)
for idnumber in idlist:
    p.write(idnumber)
    p.expect("Enter ID number:")
    text=p.before
    ... process text ...
```

Right now, it takes 18 seconds to do 100 iterations of the loop.  I tried removing all the "... process text ..." portion of my code and it did not change the speed.  My C takes less than a second to process 2500 iterations.  I have also tried implementing using QProcess and it also completes in less than a second.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/438

Comment: Thanks, but my output is only 10 lines each time

Comment: but it grows all the time

Comment: I give an input then get 10lines, then I give another input and then get another 10 lines.  Once I give another input, doesnt the old 10lines get deleted from the buffer (p.before)?

Comment: I did find a "workaround".  I implemented it using QProcess with PyQt.  Not really what I wanted though